# Gmail OAuth API fails to read client_secret.json

Tags: python, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am unable to execute the basic quickstart.py (as [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python))

The problem is with client_secret.json where the execution results in "Invalid Format error". Please note that I create a new ID for the "service account" and not for "web application" or "desktop application" account, where the resulting JSON file seems to be in the appropriate format.

Know the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The service account has a different way to make the call to get authorization, here (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)  you can fine more details on this topic if you will continue using the service account. hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try it out tonight

Comment: Turns out that I had wanted the credentials of an "installed" application. But thanks for your hint as well.